# In Phabricator, how can I browse the repository at a specific commit?

Tags: git, phabricator

Take the `phabricator` Phabricator:

https://secure.phabricator.com/source/phabricator/repository/master/

How can I browse this whole code before the last commit (`79375c6c5398`), so, after `ce0dc9a2ba2c`?

GitHub let's me do this like so:

https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/tree/ce0dc9a2ba2c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://secure.phabricator.com/source/phabricator/browse/;ce0dc9a2ba2

Phabricator provides a similar link when viewing a commit under ‘branches’ which looks like `…/<branch>/;…`. This adds a section which compares the commit to the branch but still lets you navigate the repo at that commit. Removing that section of the URL removes that part of the page, but you’ll have to create the link yourself as this link without the branch comparison doesn’t seem to be made available in the UI.